# 7 inch screen smartphones

Tags: smartphones, touchscreen

Are there any good 7 inches screen smartphones out there?

I am looking for something under android, good battery and preferably 256 gb (128 should be fine as well). My favorite brands are in order Sony, OnePlus and Google.

I tried googling but all those I find are 6.5 or sometimes 6.7 inches. Also I am not interested in Galaxy fold phones, only regular smartphones.

Is there a good Sony one with these characteristics? (I'm fine if it's 6.7 or 6.8 if it's Sony)

Comment: Beside size of screen (and in some degree the memory) do you have any other requirements? OnePlus 10T, 11 have 6.7" and are very good phones. Sony in last years have max 6.5"